# paypal sandbox not working after adding the client id

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, it's my first time trying to integrate the PayPal payment button into my Django website
I was following a tutorial and everything works fine when I used the HTML script from the PayPal developer website: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
I tested the payments and they went through successfully.
this is the working script

```
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

on the final step i should add the id where the payments go, i added the client id from my sandbox app as i followed on the tutorial.
then the payment process failed with a bunch of warnings and errors on the console log.
those are the warnings, i'm not sure if they are relevant

```
rest_api_v2_checkout_orders_capture_error 

capture_order_call_rest_api_error 

smart_api_order_capture_status_500_error
```

and the error

```
        Error: Api: /smart/api/order/2CE30645TN292790N/capture returned status code: 500 (Corr ID: 6059f74d7d86c)

{"ack":"error","message":"Unhandled api error","meta":{"calc":"6059f74d7d86c","rlog":"rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAciiXRg7dClMl1o2iporwJbYz7mI0k8X%2B5vvp6t7dnU%2B%2B_17b646b9bfe"},"server":"BW5u5z-ag5VIFXCeo-FvfHOppMovQjbfurKdnROZjue_puvEq8w7pr9g-JTUa_N93X-G1W0ItCQpDtpWzP0fjVwpK7fYmKtRr_M6AiZCc9I8jT1o-HkaNIQVCchIVE2wBsEFPkUDKrguIXjpL9HKQHXFhio_DKQgF46f__hfehX6OcSyf8EqFzCq0v_aKUbo2cn6qm-ns-fO2ozMUq0o7RWyqIHd0mDJoV8auE6OUquFw6fW65nkyx9HcNmBdsVrYFstFxkpY2W"}
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=blue&style.shape=pill&style.tagline=false&style.height=40&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVZIT2J5VTZ3VFpncG81bndtNDc2ZU9uZ3dsYjBCWmVmazhxRFpIUFpBU0J0dVNjbk5RMUVXWHF6LV9rV0tySEdPM1JHTWZLaF9ydzl0ZWcmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJ1aWRfcmhyZnFrcmRqcnJibnJ5aXNlamxqZnJkY2NscHpmIn19&clientID=AVHObyU6wTZgpo5nwm476eOngwlb0BZefk8qDZHPZASBtuScnNQ1EWXqz-_kWKrHGO3RGMfKh_rw9teg&sdkCorrelationID=af48b1f23061a&storageID=uid_59c1216f0c_mtm6mzc6mjq&sessionID=uid_ff296ed2ff_mty6mzm6ntg&buttonSessionID=uid_2b0be9f5d9_mty6mzu6ntu&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=true&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false:1317:84630
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=blue&style.shape=pill&style.tagline=false&style.height=40&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVZIT2J5VTZ3VFpncG81bndtNDc2ZU9uZ3dsYjBCWmVmazhxRFpIUFpBU0J0dVNjbk5RMUVXWHF6LV9rV0tySEdPM1JHTWZLaF9ydzl0ZWcmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJ1aWRfcmhyZnFrcmRqcnJibnJ5aXNlamxqZnJkY2NscHpmIn19&clientID=AVHObyU6wTZgpo5nwm476eOngwlb0BZefk8qDZHPZASBtuScnNQ1EWXqz-_kWKrHGO3RGMfKh_rw9teg&sdkCorrelationID=af48b1f23061a&storageID=uid_59c1216f0c_mtm6mzc6mjq&sessionID=uid_ff296ed2ff_mty6mzm6ntg&buttonSessionID=uid_2b0be9f5d9_mty6mzu6ntu&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=true&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false:1317:19688)
    at e.n.resolve (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=blue&style.shape=pill&style.tagline=false&style.height=40&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVZIT2J5VTZ3VFpncG81bndtNDc2ZU9uZ3dsYjBCWmVmazhxRFpIUFpBU0J0dVNjbk5RMUVXWHF6LV9rV0tySEdPM1JHTWZLaF9ydzl0ZWcmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJ1aWRfcmhyZnFrcmRqcnJibnJ5aXNlamxqZnJkY2NscHpmIn19&clientID=AVHObyU6wTZgpo5nwm476eOngwlb0BZefk8qDZHPZASBtuScnNQ1EWXqz-_kWKrHGO3RGMfKh_rw9teg&sdkCorrelationID=af48b1f23061a&storageID=uid_59c1216f0c_mtm6mzc6mjq&sessionID=uid_ff296ed2ff_mty6mzm6ntg&buttonSessionID=uid_2b0be9f5d9_mty6mzu6ntu&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=true&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false:1317:18745)
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=blue&style.shape=pill&style.tagline=false&style.height=40&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVZIT2J5VTZ3VFpncG81bndtNDc2ZU9uZ3dsYjBCWmVmazhxRFpIUFpBU0J0dVNjbk5RMUVXWHF6LV9rV0tySEdPM1JHTWZLaF9ydzl0ZWcmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJ1aWRfcmhyZnFrcmRqcnJibnJ5aXNlamxqZnJkY2NscHpmIn19&clientID=AVHObyU6wTZgpo5nwm476eOngwlb0BZefk8qDZHPZASBtuScnNQ1EWXqz-_kWKrHGO3RGMfKh_rw9teg&sdkCorrelationID=af48b1f23061a&storageID=uid_59c1216f0c_mtm6mzc6mjq&sessionID=uid_ff296ed2ff_mty6mzm6ntg&buttonSessionID=uid_2b0be9f5d9_mty6mzu6ntu&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=true&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false:1317:18389
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=blue&style.shape=pill&style.tagline=false&style.height=40&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVZIT2J5VTZ3VFpncG81bndtNDc2ZU9uZ3dsYjBCWmVmazhxRFpIUFpBU0J0dVNjbk5RMUVXWHF6LV9rV0tySEdPM1JHTWZLaF9ydzl0ZWcmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJ1aWRfcmhyZnFrcmRqcnJibnJ5aXNlamxqZnJkY2NscHpmIn19&clientID=AVHObyU6wTZgpo5nwm476eOngwlb0BZefk8qDZHPZASBtuScnNQ1EWXqz-_kWKrHGO3RGMfKh_rw9teg&sdkCorrelationID=af48b1f23061a&storageID=uid_59c1216f0c_mtm6mzc6mjq&sessionID=uid_ff296ed2ff_mty6mzm6ntg&buttonSessionID=uid_2b0be9f5d9_mty6mzu6ntu&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=true&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false:1317:38897)
```

is there an additional step or any solutions to make this work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing in sandbox, create [a new Sandbox business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for a new sandbox country, such as US, and then make a new sandbox REST app for that business account with a new client ID.

For later going live, if the receiving business account is in one of [the countries listed here](https://www.paypal.com/dz/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full), ensure there is a bank or visa card on the account that is capable of withdrawing funds automatically, in order for that account to be able to receive payments. This seems to be a special regulatory requirement in those countries, but have the account owner contact PayPal's general business or customer support if they need more information

Comment: i did create the sandbox REST app for the business account with a new client ID and this is the problem, the payments won't go through and those errors appears after adding the id into PayPal client id link

Comment: What sandbox country did you create the new REST app for? Update your question with the new client ID.

Comment: i created both the business and the personal account as an algerian DZ account then i created the app for the business account and used the client id of the app instead of the default id which is "test"

Comment: See my answer above, which says to use a different country. DZ is the reason it is failing.

Comment: OMG thank i just tried with a US sandbox account and it worked fine, is this means that i can't receive payments on my website with PayPal, or this only happens on the testing app??

Comment: Please read the second part of my answer.